# How can I display "01738163258" (a phone number including '0' in the first index without char,varchar type) in Oracle Database 11g

Tags: oracle

I can not understand that matter: 
How can I display "01738163258" (a phone number including '0' in the first index without char,varchar type) in Oracle Database 11g

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display the leading zero's in a number of oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968792/how-to-display-the-leading-zeros-in-a-number-of-oracle)

Comment: You are confusing data storage with data display or formatting - these are two separate concerns.

Answer (score 1):

A "telephone number" is not a number unless you're going to add them together, take the average, or the maximum, etc.

Store them as varchars with a check constraint to ensure that they meet a particular pattern -- for example that they are composed only of digits, spaces, maybe a leading "+".